# Is there a way to abstract a function that is sent as a parameter to a field in a class?

Tags: c#, class, abstraction

I'm pulling in a class from a package. That has a static readonly field that takes in a function. That function is dependent on another class (which we don't want to pull in). Is there a way to pull in the class where we can send our own method into that field? Both functions have the same return types.

```
public static class c1
{
  private static readonly ObjectPool<SHA256> Pool = new ObjectPool<SHA256>(() => CryptoUtil.Algorithms.CreateHashAlgorithm(SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest) as SHA256, 20);
}
```

but I don't want to pull in CryptoUtil.cs or the SecurityAlgorithms.cs. I want to do something like this. Create my own method CreateHashAlgorithm() and use that as a parameter.
Something like below.

```
public static class c1
{
  private static readonly ObjectPool<SHA256> Pool = new ObjectPool<SHA256>(() => CreateHashAlgorithm() as SHA256, 20);
}
```

class c1 already exists with the first implementation. I can't really change it. I don't want to create it again or copy the code to my package or anything like that. I just want to reuse it but with the change I mentioned.

```
    public static class C1
    {
        public sealed class R1
        {
            private SHA256 alg;

            public R1(SHA256 alg)
            {
                this.alg = alg;
            }

            public SHA256 Value => this.alg;
        }

        private static readonly ObjectPool<SHA256> Pool = new ObjectPool<SHA256>(() => CryptoUtil.Algorithms.CreateHashAlgorithm(SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest) as SHA256, 20);

        public static R1 GetReusableSha256() => new R1(Pool.Allocate());
    }
```

Any ideas? thank you!

Comment: `Pool` is not a property, it is a static readonly field with a field-initializer. It gets initialized before you could do anything with `c1`. Theoretically you could make a static (threadsafe, lazy, private) property from it and add some static SetHashAlgorithm method to the class, but without knowing how this field is used, I would say, it's not possible. I'm curious, if somebody else has a solution.

Comment: I can't really change the class. It's being pulled from another package which I don't own.

Comment: Then I would say, no chance...

Comment: Hmm, if I can make changes to the class, can I abstract out the CreateHashAlgorithm, so that people who are already using the class now continue using CryptoUtils.cs (first implementation), and I can use the second implementation? @Steeeve you mentioned using the SetHashAlgorithm method - Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: @PrasannaMuppidi - a `SetHashAlgorithm` is only useful if you can modify the `c1` code. You can't so you're stuck.

Comment: Probably not a good idea, but you can set the value of `Pool` in `c1` with reflection.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah yeah, I was asking if I could modify c1, is there a way to do it? - given users already using it need not change anything.

Comment: @SohaibJundi Can you explain me more?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exactly the `C1` class does and how the `Pool` field is used, this is just a hint. The added Method `SetHashAlgorithmInitializer` provides a way to use a custom hash algorithm used by `Pool` (now a property instead of a readonly field). If other not shown field-initializers would access the `Pool` property before the Method itself could change the initializer, an `InvalidOperationException` would be thrown.
I've stripped the recently added `R1` class for simplicity.

```
public static class C1
{
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    private static Func<SHA256> createHashAlgo;
    private static ObjectPool<SHA256> pool;

    private static ObjectPool<SHA256> Pool
    {
        get
        {
            // threadsafe lazy implementation
            if (pool == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (pool == null)
                    {
                        pool = new ObjectPool<SHA256>(createHashAlgo ??
                            (() => CryptoUtil.Algorithms.CreateHashAlgorithm(SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest) as SHA256),
                            20);
                    }
                }
            }
            return pool;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a callback function to provide a custom initializer for an <see cref="SHA256"/> hashalgorithm to be used by this class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="createHashAlgorithm">A callback function that must provide an instance of an <see cref="SHA256"/> algorithm on behalf.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="createHashAlgorithm"/> is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">The object pool has already been initialized with the default hash provider.</exception>
    /// <remarks>Calling <see cref="SetHashAlgorithmInitializer(Func{SHA256})"/> is optional. Not defining a custom initializer, the default <see cref="CryptoUtil.Algorithms"/> will be used.</remarks>
    public static void SetHashAlgorithmInitializer(Func<SHA256> createHashAlgorithm)
    {
        if (createHashAlgorithm is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(createHashAlgorithm));

        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (pool != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The object pool has been already initialized. The hash algorithm initializer can't be changed.");
            createHashAlgo = createHashAlgorithm;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why we are doing a thread-safe implementation here? thanks!

Comment: Static methods are usually threadsafe. And also, `Pool` as a static readonly field with an initializer was also threadsafe per definiton.